# Reverse array NOT using reverse

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to get my array to create a new array, with numbers in reverse without using the reverse method.

e.g.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(reverse(numbers))
```

should return `“[3, 2, 1]”`.

Thanks

Comment: note: arrays have a reverse method

Comment: Why not using the .reserve() method?

Comment: "I will use an for loop." ok, what is the question?

Comment: Please try instead of reverse(numbers)  this
numbers.reverse();

Comment: `const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const result = numbers.reduce((a, b) => [b].concat(a), []);`

Answer (score 2):

Here. A quick solution with map. returns you new array

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]

let result = numbers.map((el, i, arr) => arr[arr.length - 1 - i])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way using a standard for loop

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
const reverse = [];

for (let i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse.push(numbers[i])
}

console.log(reverse);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reverse = (array) => array.map(array.pop, [...array]);
console.log(reverse(numbers));
```